# How to fix late binding for datarow in datacollection where datarow variable defined in range

Tags: datarow, datarowcollection

I'm in the process of converting VB to C#.Net for my company. In order to do this more easily, I have option strict ON. I am trying to resolve a late binding on the following code. **Row** is considered an OBJECT by the compiler. I've never written code in this fashion (someone else's work). Here is the code.

```
        Dim items As List(Of Contact) = ContactsTable.GetChanges.DataTableToList(Of Contact)
    'Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim modifiedRows As DataRowCollection = From row In ContactsTable.Rows
                       Where row.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Or row.RowState = DataRowState.Added
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no way to modify the existing code. The next best option was to recode it using a "For each" loop.

```
        Dim modifiedRows As DataRowCollection = Nothing
    For each row As DataRow In ContactsTable.Rows
        If row.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Or row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
            modifiedRows.Add(row)
        End If
    Next
```